# One way Sync b/w Sql Server 2008 & SQL CE 4.0 (WPF)

Tags: c#, frameworks, sql-server-ce, synchronization

I am planning to use the sync framework to sync data between sql server 2008 & sql CE 4.0.
This is uni directional- only from sql server -> sql CE .
Updates will directly go to SQL Server 2008.
Microsoft is stating there is no Sync support for SQL Server -> SQL CE 4.0. 
Can you guide me on how to achieve syncing from sql server 2008 - SQL CE 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Sync FX with SQLCompact 4.0 - http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/sync-framework-and-sql-compact-4-yes-you-can/ or you can use RDA with 4.0 - http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/03/snapshot-synchronization-with-sql.html